# how to make "Selection.Start" start after the first 3 line?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

when searching through a document how can i skip the first 3 line of text. I am currently starting at the top of the document. I have added a code snip and i was wondering how can i start at the third line?

```
if (newSearch)
{
    lastOffset = -1;

    searchRange = new TextRange(
        body.Selection.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(1),
        body.Document.ContentEnd);

    lastSearch = searchText;
}
```

Comment: What kind of content is in the first three lines?

Comment: its the header of the document

Comment: I would say you'll need to search for some specific text that indicates the end of the header; and use that index for the start.

Comment: I always want to start the search on "CC/HPI" so now knowing that can you please show me how to start on that text.

Comment: What happens if you change `body.Selection.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(1)` to `body.Document.ContentStart.GetLineStartPosition(3)`?